# Which FFmpeg command do I use to passthrough FLV to MP4?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, flv, transcode

I've a number of downloaded FLV files which I would like to convert to MP4. They are already in the correct format so I am told all I need to do is to remux the video and audio streams into an MP4 container using copy/pass through.

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit and already have FFmpeg as part of get_iPlayer.

I'm struggling to work out the command line for this please?

Also would it be possible to batch process a number of FLV files in the same way?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://superuser.com/q/624565/148285) or [this](http://superuser.com/q/483597/148285) would help?

Answer (score 8):

It should be something like:

```
ffmpeg -i yourvideo.flv -codec copy output.mp4
```

You can use FOR command to loop through files (it recurses down your tree):

```
FOR /R C:\dir\ %%F IN (*.flv) do ffmpeg -i "%%F" -codec copy "%~nF.mp4"
```

Just to clarify, %~nF returns only the *name* portion of the filename (without the extension).

Answer (score 5):

> They are already in the correct format

.flv videos are complex files that can contain many types of audio and video. To check a .flv file's audio and video codecs you can use:

1.**ffmpeg**

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv
```

which (in your case) should output something along the lines of:

```
Input #0, flv, from 'video.flv':
  Duration: 00:05:01.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 66 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 66 kb/s, 29.92 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc 
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 22050 Hz, stereo, s16
```

or

2.**VLC's Media Information window**:
[image: VLC's Media Information window for a flv file with AAC and H.264]

This .flv file contains H.264 video and AAC audio which happens to be the correct formats/codecs for the .mp4 container.

Here's the structure of such an .mp4 file:

[image: mp4 file containing AAC audio and H.264 video]

*Image courtesy of [Converting FLV to MP4 With FFmpeg The Ultimate Guide](https://addpipe.com/blog/flv-to-mp4/)

So when transocding flv to mp4, depending on the codecs in the original .flv file, we have 4 cases:

### 1) Converting .flv files with H.264 video and AAC audio

If the audio and video codecs in the .flv files are supported by the .mp4 container (AAC + H.264) then you can just copy the streams into an mp4 file without transcoding:

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -codec copy video.mp4
```

Such .flv files are very rare.

This process is MASSIVELY faster than decoding and reencoding the entire audio and video data.

### 2) Converting .flv files with  H.264 video and Nellymoser/Speex audio

If one or more of the videos have H.264 video and Nellymoser ASAO/Speex audio (very common with .flv files) then you need to copy video (-**v**codec instead of -codec) and transcode (just) the audio:

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -vcodec copy video.mp4
```

### 3) Converting .flv files with Spark/VP6 video and Nellymoser/Speex audio

If flv's video and audio data are not encoded with the correct codecs for .mp4 (Spark & VP6 video codecs were very common) then you need to *force* both AAC and H.264:

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv video.mp4
```

### 4) Converting .flv files with Spark/VP6 video and AAC audio

It would be vary rare to come across a .flv file with AAC audio and video other than H.264, but just in case, here's how to transcode it to .mp4 in the most efficient way (copy the audio data):

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -acodec copy video.mp4
```